# fb.ui feed dialog returns empty callback in chrome and mobile devices

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I have added fb.ui feed dialog in my code to post some dynamic content with images on user's facebook timeline.

It is working fine on firefox but my problem is when user is not logged into facebook on same browser first time it asks user to get login and after login it asks user to post on facebook, after posting it returns empty callback in chrome and mobile devices.

Anyone help please.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'name here',
    link: 'link here',
    display: 'popup',
    picture: 'image url',
    //caption: 'Example Coupon',
    //redirect_uri: '',
    description: 'description here'
},
function(response) {
    console.log(response);//here it returns [] but post published, when user not logged onto facebook, when user already loggedin it return post_id
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        self.location.href = 'myurl.com?post_id='+response.post_id;
        //alert('Post was successfull published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post was not published. An Error occured');
    }
});
```

Comment: see my answer. why do you want to know if the user posted anyway, if i may ask?

Comment: if it posted successfully only then user will move forward in my scenario.

Comment: that´s not allowed then. you are not allowed to get content or reward users in any way for posting something on his wall.

Comment: is it mentioned there?

Comment: it is mentioned in the platform policy, you MUST read it before creating any app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback only returns a Post ID if you authorize the user with the `publish_actions` permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#response

**Update: publish_actions is deprecated, there is no way to post to a user profile with the API anymore.**

Comment: can i paas publish action in fb.ui method?

Comment: no, of course not. you need to use FB.login with the scope parameter.

Comment: what is ithis?Your app does not need to request the publish_actions permission in order to use the Feed Dialog, the Requests Dialog or the Send Dialog

Comment: yes? of course you don´t need it. what is your question?

Comment: if it dont need this permission then why it is not sending post_id in response with my code mention in question

Comment: yes that what i am asking if we can post without this permission then it should return post_id aswell.

Comment: but it doesn´t, that´s what i meant in my answer. you only get a post id if you authorized the user with publish_actions. that´s just how it is.

Comment: I have a same problem. I create one app in developer.facebook.com and use app id  in SDK initialization. but when I post through this sdk. resopnse is blank but post is already display in my timeline.

Comment: this is outdated, public_actions is gone anyway. are you sure you are talking about YOUR timeline, and not the timeline of a page?